# Does dimensional analysis require a dependent variable with units?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

In a dimensional analysis of `a=f(b,c,d)`, is it possible for `a` to be unitless?

I know that there are limitations on dimensionless parameters, such as the inability to represent a non-linear relationship. I want to know if any similar limitations are placed on the dependent variable.

Comment: For example, $bc/d$ with a speed, time & length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it possible for `a` to be unitless?

Yes; prominent examples are the [fine structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant) α or the [Reynolds number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number).

Comment: I had not considered that the Reynolds number could be the dependent variable in a dimensional analysis; I have only seen it as one of the PI groups.